# Select single row from relation table in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

Is there a simpler way of returning the relationship row from a table to access the data stored there?

I have two models related using has_many :through and the third model set up as the in-between. My models consist of a User, Recipe, and RecipeInfo.

Right now, in order to access the data stored for a particular user's recipe info, I'm using a Rails query similar to this

`info = @user.recipeInfos.where("recipe_id=#{@recipe.id}")`

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way of accessing this single row of a User's Recipe info rather than using the .where() method.

Edit:

`recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])`

`user = current_user`

`current_user` is defined by `sessions[:user_id] = current_user` when the user logs in.

Comment: Just for a bit of code context, how are you determining which recipe to look for (how is @recipe determined)?

Comment: I've edited my question with the context.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `where`? `@user.recipeInfos.where(:recipe_id => @recipe.id).first` will automatically limit it to single result, if that's what you're worried about. Unrelated, why the unusual capitalization of `recipeInfos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten those four lines of code to just

```
info = current_user.recipeInfos.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

.